# Xcode 7 size class issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, size-classes

So I have an app and I want a very different layout based on size class. And I thought I'd accomplished this today because the storyboard preview showed every device and every size in every orientation doing exactly what it was supposed to do. When I ran this on my device and then the simulator however, the size class seemed not to change as the layout was pretty much the same thing as before. Here is screenshot showing my issue. Please note that the psycho spray painting was done by me not Xcode:

[image: This shows the simulator on the left and the storyboard preview on the right. The image view seen in the preview is shown overlapping the slider in the simulator.]

So I was hoping someone could help. In case you're wondering, I did the psycho spray painting to protect some confidential info which I thought was pretty obvious but there you go :)

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of all constraints for the two main size classes. The green and blue objects that are blanked out do correspond. So the blue thing up top is the blue thing in the constraints. The green is label and slider of the same part of the app's functionality which I don't want to reveal. For now all I'll say is that it's a music app as you can tell by looking at the photos below.

[image: Compact Width, Any Height]
[image: Any Width, Compact Height]

Comment: Please list out your constraints

Comment: There you go @Msencenb

Comment: Looks like you solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the problem! I forgot to resolve some issues in my Compact width and compact height (aka 3.5,4,and 4.7 inch iPhones in landscape) which forced it to use the previous size class's layout.